# How to retain ownership/permissions when using cloud backup (Backblaze B2)

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 and backing up some data from an ext4 partition to [Backblaze B2](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/cloud-storage.html) using the [rclone](https://rclone.org/b2/) tool.  The issue I have is that when restoring these backups, I am able to download a ZIP file to restore my files.  When I extract these files they ALL have permissions of 664, although the permissions in the original directory are different than 664.  I have multiple files with varying permissions, but when restored they are always 664 (see below).

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername myusername  219 Oct 26 05:00 myfilename.txt
```

Is there a simple way to backup/restore permissions to a cloud provider using rclone, especially Backblaze C2?  For now I am using getfacl and setfacl, but I would prefer it to be automatic when I use rclone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Backblaze but the general solution is to put your files into a suitable archive (e.g. tar) and make a backup of that archive into the cloud. The archive contains (most of) the Unix permissions so when you restore first the archive file and then the real files from the archive you should get the old permission state.

Comment: My issue is that I want to have incremental backups at an hourly interval.  My backup is 200GB+.  Is a tar archive suitable for doing incremental updates to a remote server like this? Thank you

Comment: @niij Yes, tar can do incremental backups.